# Perplexing IE issue with auto margins

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margins

I've had 2 people looking at this all morning, and I can't seem to figure out why IE 8 and 7 is pushing my entire page over to the left. Not having any issues in any other browsers. There is also an problem with the menu, it doesn't seem to work on this page either. Can anyone spot what is going on here? Any help would certainly be appreciated.

http://wineexcursion.com/dev/index.php/event_info/event_schedule/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment at the top of the markup is forcing IE to render in Quirks mode, which is what is causing the problems.  In IE, if anything precedes the doctype in the markup, it triggers Quirks mode rendering.

From the page source:

```
<!-- Brown Callout/Brown Sidebar -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

If I use IE dev tools to force the page into standards mode, the page centers as it should and the menu works.